# Type trait through a variable of the type

Tags: c++

I'd like to test a property of the type of a variable. I do can it, but the code is too verbose.

Consider an example, in which I define a variable of the same type as the type of a value in a container:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v, &rv=v;

  // ‘rv’ is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
  //rv::value_type i1;

  // Ok
  decltype(v)::value_type i2;

  // decltype evaluates to ‘std::vector<int>&’, which is not a class or enumeration type
  //decltype(rv)::value_type i3;

  // Ok
  std::remove_reference<decltype(rv)>::type::value_type i4;
}
```

I can live with `decltype`, but adding `std::remove_reference` is too much. Are there any nice way to shorten the code, without defining auxiliary templates?

Comment: What property is it that you want to test? (This looks a lot like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: Dunno, the `remove_reference` line does not look that bad to me, esp. considering you are not going to do this dozens of times. That being said, the answer is probably "no".

Comment: if you're using it repeatedly, perhaps use a `using` statement and alias it to `value_type` or something

Comment: Yes, this is a X-Y problem. The actual problem ("X") was to check that two maps have the same key comparator, and `decltype(m.key_comp())` was a solution. However, I'm curious if it is possible to make "Y".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shorten that with one of

```
std::decay_t<decltype(rv)>::value_type i4 = 42;
```

or

```
std::decay_t<decltype(*std::begin(rv))> i4 = 42;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some *using declarations*:

```
using my_value_type = decltype(v)::value_type;
using your_value_type = std::remove_reference<decltype(rv)>::type::value_type;
```

Your code will become:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v, &rv=v;

    using my_value_type = decltype(v)::value_type;
    using your_value_type = std::remove_reference<decltype(rv)>::type::value_type;

    my_value_type i2;
    your_value_type i4;
}
```